# elasticsearch nested aggregration total value

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents with category, respsize, client name etc. as you see in picture below..
[image]

I want to get result by dsl query which returns filtered by category and grouped by clientname then total respsize in each category of that user.. here what I tried:
[image]

But I want respsize of each categories in this result also it should be like:

```
"buckets": [
                 {
                    "key": "50",
                    "doc_count": 87,
                    "respsize": 23213                     
                 },
                 {
                    "key": "49",
                    "doc_count": 25,
                    "respsize": 23213
                 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this agg ;-)

```
"aggs": {
    "by_clients": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "clientname"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_categories": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "category"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "total_respsize": {
              "sum": {"field": "respsize"}
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```